Pathogenic Hive-Intelligence When Critical Mass is Reached
Could there be a virus or amoeba or protist or bacteria (or fungal but that is over-used in pop culture) that infects humans (and possibly other lifeforms) that by itself is not sentient but as they increase in number they bump up against each other and start to share information (via electro-chemical signals) to the point that when enough are connected (amassed) they become sentient almost as if each individual pathogen is a neuron and when enough of them link up they produce thought. Is there any plausible or semi-plausible (borderline fantasy) way of making this work? Thanks! Similar to the notion of the Giant Polyp (https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/The_Giant_Polyp#:~:text=An%20intelligent%20but%20rather%20unusual,retracting%20tentacles%20and%20articulated%20limbs.)

Thanks Pica, I actually deleted it in fear that I was annoying people with a broad question, but thank you so much for your answer, I am reviewing it now!

You may want to become acquainted with the life history of slime molds, notably the Dictyolstelids which exhibit an astonishing duality between individual amoebae and coordinated, moving multicellular assemblies which are able to respond to light and temperature gradients.

Thanks AlexP, they were actually part of my inspiration aside from the Arthur C Clarke on I cited in my post. With a little finessing and whimsy I could make it semi-plausible I suppose. Would you suggest a pathogenic amoeba versus another type of lifeform or virus then?

Could there be? The nature of evolution is that given enough time anything is possible. The nature of this Stack is that we help you build an imaginary world where anything is possible. So... sure! The idea of a micro-hive mind has been used before - pick your poison: virus, a goo that covers about half the earth, nanites... Are you asking if there's an actual Real World way to do this? Not exactly our purpose... and if there were, whomever knew how would be running to the patent office. What's the question again?

Haha JBH, true true! Yes, I have decided upon a fungus (but altering the approach to it so that it is divergent from mainstream iterations as much as I can!). A fungus seemed to me to be the most adaptable due to the genome similarities with animals that would work well weaving into my story. IT is going to be a mixture of the slime mold concept, the great polyp from Arthur C Clarke and a dash of the Flood/Gravemind from Halo.

It's totally possible, Mycorriza for exemple are symbiotic links between fungi hyphae and plant roots underground, this interconected system can share information between trees regarding predators, parasites and diseases, this plus the comunication that happen on air, both are chemical and are very slow compared to our mode of thinking, maybe too slow and uncoordinated to develop true thinking, but your hypothetical pathogen may have other ways to circumvent that, I hope it was helpful.
